# Does Tensorflow support CUDA 11.6?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda

I am trying to install Tensorflow with CUDA 11.6 for deeplabcut to run on GPU but I am getting errors. I did not find any documents that show support for TF on CUDA 11.6.

Comment: Nvidia's current TF build supports Cuda SDK 11.7: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_22-06.html

Comment: TensorFlow is specifically about programming, so it definitely is within the scope of Stackoverflow.com

Comment: Asking a concrete question about writing code using Tensorflow is "specifically about programming". Asking an abstract support question about compatibility between some undefined binary release of Tensorflow and a specific release of CUDA (or the other way around as the question was originally written, which makes even less sense) isn't.

Comment: It belongs to *software tools commonly used by programmers* https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic together with *Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming.* I agree that the question is of bad quality and missing necessary information. But off-topic? Definitely not.

Answer (score 3):

[As of tensorflow version 2.9.0](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) (the latest version as of this post), you need CUDA 11.2.

If you had, say 11.2.6 (example, not sure if it exists), it'd work fine.

- 11.1 won't work
- 11.2 will work
- 11.2.6 will work
- 11.3 will not work
- 11.6 will not work

Comment: Hmm, this comment contradicts you: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/54384#issuecomment-1043467342

Comment: Possibly, my answer was following documentation.